# How to bind Database values to combo box in Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, combobox

I am Using Combobox in my Windows application and binding values to combo box from database as show below

```
public void LoadDatsbaseNames()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name FROM sys.databases ORDER BY name", connection))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            DataRow dr;
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, "---Select--" };
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
            cbDBName.DisplayMember = "name";
            cbDBName.DataSource = dt;
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

But the Above Method showing an error

> Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

Comment: I am Having Total 39 Databases in my Local server.

Comment: you are binding only name to the combo box ? where is your Id associated with it

Comment: you are inserting dr of two item and your query only returns one value (i.e. column) thats why giving error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to create DataRow if you only want to bind combobox because DataTable is already filled with data you just only bind it with combobox.

```
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name FROM sys.databases ORDER BY name", connection))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    cbDBName.DisplayMember = "name";
    cbDBName.DataSource = dt;
    connection.Close();
}
```

Also you do not need to close connection manually because you are using `using statement` it will take care of this.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If i remove DataBind(). In dropdown it is showing System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: Add cbDBName.ID = "name";

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now your query works Fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void BindVendorDDL()
        {
            ddlVendor.Items.Clear();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = bl.BindCompanyDLL();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ddlVendor.Text = "--Select--";
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    ddlVendor.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Vendor_name"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```